# Does Sencha Touch offer any security model?

Tags: security, mobile-application, sencha-touch-2

Does Sencha Touch offer any security model?

How compatible it is with custom or other predefined security models like Spring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sencha Touch is agnostic:  that is, it neither provides a security model of its own nor limits you to the use of a particular server-side model.  If Spring is your thing, and if its security model is accessible by a REST-like API (which is the case), then it's perfectly feasible.

That said, there are at least two other dimensions to consider:  one is transport layer security, the other is encrypted local storage.  Sencha has nothing to do with these, either, but they're also important to your app.  TLS is a deployment concern; encrypted local storage is more or less a DIY project, although there are some libraries out there to assist, [javascrypt](http://www.fourmilab.ch/javascrypt/) and [Stanford Javascript Crypto Library](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.com/sjcl/) among them.

Comment: Thank you Euhe for your answer. Thats pretty much clear about the security in Sencha Touch apps

Comment: any suggestion to secure any server request or response?

Comment: Using TLS (https) is an easy way to get started